# TcpSocket bind to eth0 ipv6 address returns { code: 22, kind: InvalidInput, message: "Invalid argument" }

Tags: networking, rust, ipv6, tcpsocket

By trying to bing local routable IPv6 address(provided by eth0 and starting with fe80::) I get `{ code: 22, kind: InvalidInput, message: "Invalid argument" }`

```rust
fn foo() {
    let d = TcpSocket::new_v6();
    d.bind(local_address).unwrap(); // local_address is like "fe80::..."
}
```

Comment: IPv6 link-local addresses (`fe80::/10`) require a Zone ID because _every_ interface uses the same link-local network. The Zone ID is specific to the host OS.

Comment: fe80::*****/64. how to get zoned id and specify as a part of binding?

ping6 -I eth0 fe80::**** works as expected

PING fe80::208:54ff:fe34:22ae(fe80::208:54ff:fe34:22ae) from fe80::***%eth0 eth0: 56 data bytes

Comment: Yes, on the host it is `/64`, but the RFC says `/10` with the next 54 bit as zero, so it works out to `/64`, which is in the `/10` network. The Zone ID is something like `%2` for Windows, `%eth0` for something else, etc. It depends on the OS, version, and interface. The RFC leaves it up to the OS vendor, so there is no way to answer that because it is specific to your host.

Comment: See [RFC 6874](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6874.html).